# fs::dir_tree() - sort directory tree

Tags: r, directory, tidyverse

For a rmarkdown project documentation I'd like to include some tree structures of directories using the `dir_tree()` command from the `fs`-package. I would like to order the output like files are usually ordered in Windows when you sort by name, e.g. folders at the top and then the files in alphabetical order. Currently the output is looking like this:

```
path/to/folder
+-- exfile1.txt
+-- subfolder1
|   +-- excelfile.xlsx
|   \-- subsubfolder
|       \-- textfile.txt
\-- subfolder2
    \-- an image.bmp
```

My desired output:

```
path/to/folder
+-- subfolder1
|   +-- subsubfolder
|   |   \-- textfile.txt
|   \-- excelfile.xlsx
+-- subfolder2
|   \-- an image.bmp
\-- exfile1.txt
```

I've read through the documentation but I've not been able to sort the tree structure. Is this possible or are there any alternatives to get an ordered directory tree? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there are any options in that package to do what you want, but it's fairly simple to modify the `dir_tree` function to do it.  Just add the line

```
files <- files[order(!is_dir(files))]
```

near the start, just after `files` is created.  Unless you recompile the package, this won't be persistent, so I'd put the new function into the start of your document, using something like this:

```
dir_tree_sorted <- function(path = ".", recurse = TRUE, ...) {
  files <- dir_ls(path, recurse = recurse, ...)
  files <- files[order(!is_dir(files))]
  by_dir <- split(files, path_dir(files))

  ch <- box_chars()

  get_coloured_name <- function(x) {
    coloured <- colourise_fs_path(x)
    sub(x, path_file(x), coloured, fixed = TRUE)
  }

  print_leaf <- function(x, indent) {
    leafs <- by_dir[[x]]
    for (i in seq_along(leafs)) {
      if (i == length(leafs)) {
        cat(indent, pc(ch$l, ch$h, ch$h, " "), get_coloured_name(leafs[[i]]), "\n", sep = "")
        print_leaf(leafs[[i]], paste0(indent, "    "))
      } else {
        cat(indent, pc(ch$j, ch$h, ch$h, " "), get_coloured_name(leafs[[i]]), "\n", sep = "")
        print_leaf(leafs[[i]], paste0(indent, pc(ch$v, "   ")))
      }
    }
  }

  cat(colourise_fs_path(path), "\n", sep = "")
  print_leaf(path_expand(path), "")

  invisible(files)
}
environment(dir_tree_sorted) <- environment(fs::dir_tree)
```

The last line is important:  without it, the function won't look in the right place for internals of the package.

P.S.  This also fixes a bug in `dir_tree` that causes it to fail on something like `dir_tree("~")`.